# MySQL Time Series Operation

Tags: mysql, time-series

I am using MySQL in version 5.6. (Mentioned because non-presence of usable mysql functions)

Given a table with "motion detection" timestamps. With every row got a motion detected. No motion means no entry.

```
Id | Date Time
---------------
1  | 2018-01-01 15:00:01  // Start of activity phase 1
2  | 2018-01-01 15:00:03
3  | 2018-01-01 15:00:06  // Stop of activity phase 1
// Non-Activity phase
4  | 2018-01-01 17:01:06  // Start of activity phase 2
5  | 2018-01-01 17:02:06
6  | 2018-01-01 17:02:09  // Stop of activity phase 2
// Non-Activity phase, big one because of holiday
7  | 2018-01-10 19:40:06  // Start of activity phase 3
8  | 2018-01-10 19:41:06  // Stop of activity phase 3
```

I struggle to find a SQL query that give me an overview of "**activity phases**".

What I try to get is something like:

```
Id | Activity starts     | Activity ends
---------------------------------------------
1  | 2018-01-01 15:00:01 | 2018-01-01 15:00:06
2  | 2018-01-01 17:01:06 | 2018-01-01 17:02:09
3  | 2018-01-10 19:40:06 | 2018-01-10 19:41:06
```

I would like to see the start and end timestamps of an "**activity phase**".
Definition of an "**activity phase**": An "**activity phase**" is located between two "**non-activity phases**" of (e.g) at least 30minutes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where I can read the activy phase linked to id / date time?

Comment: Hi, all I have is data shown in listing 1, I look for a query that produces something like shown in listing 2.

Comment: In your list 1 only info about activy phase is your comment. You can't reach your aim with those data

Comment: Thanks again, I think the problem is not understood or badly explained. Speaking about listing 1: 
Between ID 3 and 4 are no other rows. So, between 2018-01-01 15:00:06 and 2018-01-01 17:01:06 no motions got detected. This is an non-activity phase, because it is longer than 30minutes. Activity phases are everything that not contain a (row:row+1) >= 30minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the working answer from @Nick, I spent some hours more to find the following solution:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @row_number2 = 0;
SET @gap_time = "00:30:00";
Select
  "",
  DAYNAME(prep1.datetime2) "Weekday",
  prep1.datetime2 "Activity starts",
  prep2.datetime1 "Activity ends"

FROM

(SELECT
 (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num
 ,detection1.id id1
 ,detection1.insert_datetime datetime1
 ,detection2.id id2
 ,detection2.insert_datetime datetime2
 ,timediff(detection2.insert_datetime,detection1.insert_datetime) as diff
FROM
 MOVEMENT_TRACKING detection1,
 MOVEMENT_TRACKING detection2
WHERE
 detection1.id + 1 = detection2.id
 and timediff(detection2.insert_datetime,detection1.insert_datetime)  > @gap_time
order by detection1.id) as prep1,

(SELECT
 (@row_number2:=@row_number2 + 1) AS num
 ,detection1.id id1
 ,detection1.insert_datetime datetime1
 ,detection2.id id2
 ,detection2.insert_datetime datetime2
 ,timediff(detection2.insert_datetime,detection1.insert_datetime) as diff
FROM
 MOVEMENT_TRACKING detection1,
 MOVEMENT_TRACKING detection2
WHERE
 detection1.id + 1 = detection2.id
 and timediff(detection2.insert_datetime,detection1.insert_datetime)  > @gap_time
order by detection1.id) as prep2

WHERE
 prep1.num + 1 = prep2.num
ORDER BY
 prep1.datetime2 DESC
```

Some reductions are still possible, I let them in because of debugging reasons. Some hacks were needed like

```
Select ""
```

because of database-hosting security police rules.

Comment: This looks like the path I originally went down. I couldn't make it work when there were 4 or more movements detected in one activity phase. From playing around with your query on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53a7e9) it looks like yours doesn't either?

Comment: Ah thanks, there are some problems with upper and lower boundaries. Didn't recognize that, but not sure how much impact in real life. Check out: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02b12/1/3

Comment: Weird, your SQLFiddle worked for four where mine didn't... Although as you say it is missing the first and last entries. It would be interesting to see the speed difference between the two methods on a big table; I could see 3 cross-joins getting pretty expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to achieve this in MySQL 5.6 is with a stored procedure (although I'd love to see someone prove me wrong). This one will do what you want. Note that it returns a number of single row result sets so you need to deal with that in the application framework. Alternatively you could modify the procedure to store intermediate results into a temporary table and then `SELECT` everything from the temporary table at the end of the procedure (see below).

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_activity //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_activity()
BEGIN
  DECLARE start, thistime, lasttime DATETIME;
  DECLARE activity_count INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE activity_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT atime FROM activity;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
  OPEN activity_cursor;
  FETCH activity_cursor INTO start;
  SET lasttime = start;
  act_loop: LOOP
    FETCH activity_cursor INTO thistime;
    IF finished = 1 THEN
      SELECT activity_count, start, lasttime AS end;
      LEAVE act_loop;
    END IF;
    IF thistime > lasttime + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE THEN
      SELECT activity_count, start, lasttime AS end;
      SET start = thistime;
      SET activity_count = activity_count + 1;
    END IF;
    SET lasttime = thistime;
  END LOOP;
END //
```

For your sample data, this procedure returns:

```
activity_count  start                   end     
1               2018-01-01 15:00:01     2018-01-01 15:00:06
activity_count  start                   end     
2               2018-01-01 17:01:06     2018-01-01 17:02:09
activity_count  start                   end     
3               2018-01-10 19:40:06     2018-01-10 19:41:06
```

Here's the procedure with the temporary table:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_activity //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_activity()
BEGIN
  DECLARE start, thistime, lasttime DATETIME;
  DECLARE activity_count INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE activity_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT atime FROM activity;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE activity_temp (id INT, start DATETIME, end DATETIME);
  OPEN activity_cursor;
  FETCH activity_cursor INTO start;
  SET lasttime = start;
  act_loop: LOOP
    FETCH activity_cursor INTO thistime;
    IF finished = 1 THEN
      INSERT INTO activity_temp VALUES (activity_count, start, lasttime);
      LEAVE act_loop;
    END IF;
    IF thistime > lasttime + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE THEN
      INSERT INTO activity_temp VALUES (activity_count, start, lasttime);
      SET start = thistime;
      SET activity_count = activity_count + 1;
    END IF;
    SET lasttime = thistime;
  END LOOP;
  SELECT * FROM activity_temp;
  DROP TABLE activity_temp;
END //
```

Output (from `CALL get_activity()`):

```
id  start                   end     
1   2018-01-01 15:00:01     2018-01-01 15:00:06
2   2018-01-01 17:01:06     2018-01-01 17:02:09
3   2018-01-10 19:40:06     2018-01-10 19:41:06
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I will try it out within the next 10 hours.